# Firewall Iptables block everything and allow vpn

Tags: iptables, pptp

I would like to block all traffic on my ubuntu server with `iptables` and them allow only the protocols : HTTP, HTTPS, PPTP, L2TP, SSTP and OpenVPN

I have tried many ways to do this, and I would like to have a clean start, so if someone can give me an idea what is the best way to do this I will really appreciate.

Comment: I thought you just use the -p for protocol and then http or tcp...